# nginx + cloudflare + digitalocean = 521

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I'm trying host a website with multiple subdomains (created with Cloudflare, which also provides SSL) hosted on DigitalOcean with Nginx serving as a reverse proxy.

My Cloudflare Configs

DNS setup:

```
Type ~ Name ~ Value
A ~ api ~ MyDigitalOceanIPv4
A ~ example.com ~ MyDigitalOceanIPv4
A ~ www ~ MyDigitalOceanIPv4
```

Crypto setup:

```
SSL: Full (strict)
Always use HTTPS: On 
Automatic HTTPS Rewrites: On
```

I've also used Cloudflare to Create Certificate (and followed their instructions to set it up with Nginx)

My Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /srv/example.com/cloudflare.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/example.com/cloudflare.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name api.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /srv/example.com/cloudflare.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/example.com/cloudflare.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

I have opened for all TCP ports on DigitalOcean, and if I try to open MyDigitalOceanIPv4:8000 in my browser then my website (hosted in a Docker container) successfully loads. However, if I try to open my website "example.com" then I get Cloudflare's 521 web server is down message.

I have also verified that the Cloudflare SSL key paths and content are correct, `nginx -t` shows no errors, and I've made sure to restart nginx after making changes.

I have also tried to whitelist Cloudflare's IPs using my Nginx config file but it didn't work.

If I try to `telnet MyDigitalOceanIPv4 443` or 80 then I get `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`.

Inside my DigitalOcean instance I have tried to curl `http://localhost:8000` which successfully prints my website content.

I suspect there's some DigitalOcean setting I need to configure, or there's something wrong with my Nginx file (even though I've successfully used same Nginx config on a different cloud provider), but feel like I've tried everything..

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?

Comment: @saitam I solved it by redoing everything on a new droplet, so I can't say exactly what was wrong, but I know there is nothing wrong with any of the setups. My suggestions would be to check that (1) check you're actually using the right IP on cloudflare dns, (2) that you didn't make a port typo (e.g. 433 instead of 443), (3) that your nginx config is actually being loaded (you can easily test this by updating ssl_certificate to a path that doesn't exist and run nginx -t to see if it displays any errors), (4) if you're using ufw that you've allowed https traffic